# How to create FUNC Action List with Parameters and Return Values

Tags: c#, func

I am trying to create my first list of actions that I will be able to check a status within the passed object.

But I can't get it to work - its giving me an error on the return type.  But if I change the return type to what it wants - then I can't pass values down.

Sample code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Main()
    {
        var decisionObject = new DecisionObject();

        var decisionList = new List<Func<DecisionObject, DecisionObject>>
        {
            Method1(decisionObject),
            Method2(decisionObject),
            Method3(decisionObject)
        };

        var exitLoop = false;

        foreach (var method in decisionList)
        {
            decisionObject = method(decisionObject);


            switch (decisionObject.Status)
            {
                case Status1:
                    exitLoop = true;
                    break;
                case Status2:
                case Status3:
                case Status4:
                    break;
            }

            if (exitLoop) break;
        }
     }  


 public Func<DecisionObject, DecisionObject> Method1(DecisionObject 
 decisionObject)
 {
     decisionObject = SomeOtherMethod(decisionObject);

     return decisionObject;
 }   


 }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `its giving me an error` **Always** assume the next question someone will ask is **what was the error**?

Comment: I assume it's the return type of Method1. But please correct me if wrong.

Comment: Correct - The type is not of type Func....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, `Method1`,`Method2`, and `Method3` are simply supposed to accept a decision object and return a different one. So they would be defined like this (hopefully this is straightforward to you):

```
DecisionObject Method1(DecisionObject input)
{
    var output = SomeMethod(input);
    return output;
}
```

You then want to put all these methods into a list and execute them. To put them into a list, put the method names in the code *without parentheses*. That tells C# that you want a reference to the method itself, rather than the result of invoking the method.

```
var decisionList = new List<Func<DecisionObject, DecisionObject>>
    {
        Method1,  //Do not invoke-- just store a reference to the method
        Method2,
        Method3
    };
```

You can then invoke them by passing the decision object in:

```
foreach (var func in decisionList)
{
    var result = func(decisionObject);
}
```

The key thing here to remember is that **when you put parentheses after a symbol, it tells C# to invoke it**.  So don't put parentheses if all you want is a reference to the method itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
decisionObject = SomeOtherMethod(decisionObject)
```

Isn't probably returning a func but a value.

You could do this:

```cs
public Func<DecisionObject, DecisionObject> Method1()
{
    var myFunc = (myObject) => SomeOtherMethod(myObject);
    return myFunc;
}
```

That will create and returns a new func that expects one parameter and invokes SomeOtherMethod.

Please note that the parameter of Method1 isn't needed in this approach and so I removed it.

Comment: Can't fully test it yet but it looks like this works.  Thank you.